# Understanding search('\S\_.*\n\_.*\%#', 'b')

Tags: regex, vim

I am in the middle of Damian Conway's "Scripting Vim" by O'Reilly. Conway uses the abbreviation:

`iabbr <expr> ^^- getline(search('\S\_.*\n\_.*\%#','b'))` 
i know getline(**n**) will get the contents of the line number **n**

and search(**p**) will move to the cursor to the first match of pattern **p** and return the line number of the match. In this case it searches backwards because the of the flag 'b' and the search will wrap around to the end of the buffer if no match is found.

to brake down the pattern:

`\S`     matches any character/digit BUT a `<tab>` or `<space>`

`\_.*`     matches any single character or end of line character (greedy)

`\n`     matches newline character

`\%#`     matches cursor position

i cant see how this search pattern matches the line before the cursor ?

In an attempt to understand this abbreviation i found an alternative way

`iabbr <expr> ^^- getline((line('.') -1))`

Answer (score 0):

> i cant see how this search pattern matches the line before the cursor ?

It doesn't, at least not on its own. It's the `b` flag in `:help search()` that ties it all together.

> In an attempt to understand this abbreviation i found an alternative way
> `iabbr <expr> ^^- getline((line('.') -1))`

That's not an alternative. The original snippet doesn't insert "the content of the line above", it inserts the content of "the first non-empty line above", which is smarter, and a little bit trickier.

In order to better understand how it works, I'd suggest you try the pattern on the command-line, starting from the end, atom-by-atom, with a short sample:

```
foo
bar


baz
 ^ cursor here
```

- First atom from the end (`\%#` is not really worth trying on its own): `?\_.*\%#`.
- Then add the second: `?\n\_.*\%#`.
- Then the third: `?\_.*\n\_.*\%#`.
- Then the fourth: `?\S\_.*\n\_.*\%#`.

See `:help 'incsearch'` in a recent enough Vim for highlighting the match in real time.

To be honest, I find this over-complicated. The author may have come upon some corner cases while putting his pattern together, which might explain the complexity, but it looks to me like a simpler `\S\s*\n` would be enough. YMMV.

Anyway, throwing complicated snippets like this one at unsuspecting readers without explaining them is, in my opinion, irresponsible.